# pthreads: trying to write rows of a large array using multiple threads in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to get pthreads to work in C (mac/Monterey). I have a 2d array with one row to be filled in by each thread.  I pass these to the workers (compute_trajectory) using:

```
pthread_create(&threads[ii], NULL, compute_trajectory, (int *) traj_set[ii]);
```

compute_trajectory recasts its argument from `int *` back to an array of structures and fills in the data

I then use calls:

```
pthread_join(threads[ii], NULL);
```

to synchronise after the execution of all threads.

When I run with a single thread everything works fine.

When I run with say 8 threads, I get NANs creeping into the arrays (but not initially).

Comment: Hi @beanL, you're supposed to post your problem with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to get better help.

Comment: Of what type is `traj_set`? An array of `int` cant be NaN.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.